# getJSON async with get - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a getJSON very large, and while this load all data in the document, how i can do to read other getJSON data while this is yet loading?

the event in .on( is detected, but the getJSON not, is detected only when the another getJSON is loaded all

```
    $.getJSON('./master-list.php?q=master', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if(i >= 120)
                return false;

            addServer(item);
        });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.servergetid', function() {
        console.log('Hey!');

        $('#pd').html('');
        $.ajax({
          url: './data.php?ip=' + $(this).data('server') + '&data=l_by_id',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'GET',
          async: true,
          success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.players, function(i, item) {
                $('#pd').append('<tr><td>' + item.Nickname + '</td><td>' + item.Score + '</td></tr>');
            });
          }
        });
    });

function addServer(ip)
{
    var response = false;
    $.getJSON('./data.php?ip=' + ip + '&data=info', function(data)
    {
        response = addServerInfo(data, '[x]');
    });
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, the solution is change async: true to async: false, thanks.